# How do I use a vector of indices to extract rows from a matrix?

Tags: r, subset

I have two matrices, `M1` (6400x6) and `M2` (315x3)

`M2` is a subset of `M1`. I did some data imputation on `M2` and now I would like to use `M2`'s row indices to extract the corresponding rows from the `M1`. How can I approach this?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly did you extract `M2` from `M1`? this will be essential to proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that might help:

```
m1 <- matrix(runif(5000),ncol=50) #define a large matrix with random numbers
m2 <- m1[5:17,8:30] #create a subset starting from index [5,8]
#How to retrieve the information on the location of m2 within m1:
idx <- which(m1 %in% m2, arr.ind = TRUE)[1]
rownum <- idx %% nrow(m1)
colnum <- ceiling(idx / nrow(m1))
#> rownum
#[1] 5
#> colnum
#[1] 8
```

This means that the initial point of the subset m2 (the upper left corner, so to say) is located within the larger matrix m1 at row 5, column 8.

I hope this helps. However, if you have performed more complex modifications and the subset is not just a simple rectangular cluster of the large matrix with entries ordered in the same way, then I believe that you will need to provide more information on what you have done to construct the submatrix in order to obtain a helpful answer.